# SSRS report export to excel functionality gives faulty report

Tags: excel, reporting-services, decimal, ssrs-2012

In the SSRS my report is displayed fine I have the following scenario:

I am passing a parameter `ShowDecimal`. If the value of the `ShowDecimal` is `Y` then decimals should be displayed in the report.

Catch is, if the value is like `1` it should display it as `1`, if the value is like `1.10` then the value should be displayed as `1.10.`

If the `ShowDecimal` is `N` then do not show the decimals.

I have added condition in the format like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowDecimal.Value="Y", "#,##0.##", "#,##0")
```

In the report the values are displayed are proper, but when I export them to excel `.` is coming after the values.

Like in the report the value is `**10**` and in the excel the value is
displayed as `**10.**`

**SSRS Report in the VS viewer:**
[image]

**Exported excel report:**

[image]

Comment: You can convert the field value into a String, this way Excel will display it also as a String and it would be like you want it. On the other side this doenst make sense to display a numerical value as a String. The best solution here would be to display the field always as decimal with 2 places after the dot in SSRS and in Excel

Comment: @Strawberryshrub I am new in the SSRS reports , Can you guide me how i can convert value in the string at least i can try that.

Comment: Yes SSRS recognizes this expression, but Excel not. Excel just knows String or Number. To convert it into String just wrap your whole field/expression in `CStr()` and set the textbox properties format to `Default`

Comment: I have changed the custom format to =IIF(Parameters!ShowDecimal.Value="Y",Format(Cstr(Fields!CurYrChanges.Value),"#,##0.##"),Format(Cstr(Fields!CurYrChanges.Value),"#,##0")), Still it does not work. Can you please guide me ?

Comment: This way: `=CStr(IIF(Parameters!ShowDecimal.Value="Y",Format(Fields!CurYrChanges.Value,"#,##0.##"),Format(Fields!CurYrChanges.Value),"#,##0")`.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub In the above format the '.' is not coming. The string comes '2732337' in the report. in the excel it is proper '27323.37' , I don't think like this is possible to do. I have to negotiate either in the report or in the excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188584/discussion-between-developer-and-strawberryshrub).